# Ramda, find value in sub array

Tags: ramda.js

My previous javascript underscore function:

```
export const getQuantity = (obj, name: string) => {
  const quantityInIfcObject = _.findWhere(obj.quantities, { name: quantity });
  return quantityInIfcObject ? quantityInIfcObject.value : null;
};
const quantity = getQuantity(obj, 'area');
```

What would a Ramda-version of this look like?

Tried this:

```
export const getQuantity = (name) =>  R.pipe(
  R.map((o: IIfcObject) => o.quantities),
  R.find(R.propEq('name', name)),
  R.map((q: IIfcQuantity) => q.value)
)(quantity);
const quantity = getQuantity(obj, 'area');
```

Not working. In the examples I've read of `pipe` there's no arguments. Maybe wrong to use pipe here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `quantities` (R.prop), find the name, and get the `value` if exists, or `null` if it doesn't:

```
export const getQuantity = (name) => R.pipe(
  R.prop('quantities'),
  R.find(R.propEq('name', name)),
  R.propOr(null, 'value'),
)(quantity);
```

Calling the function is a two steps process, since R.pipe returns a function when invoked. When you call `getQuantity('area')`, R.pipe will return a function. That function expects an object to operate on:

```
const getQuantityForArea = getQuantity('area');
const quantity = getQuantityForArea(obj);
```

You can call it in one step by combining both calls:

```
const quantity = getQuantity('area')(obj);
```